# batch file to open multiple command prompts and execute the same task

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want a batch script which opens up multiple command prompt on a single click   and runs the same command over and over again . i have written a below code which only opens an single command prompt and stops there .is there a way to do the same.

```
   for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    start cmd /c 
    cd / && dir /s
   )
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
   for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    start cmd /c "cd / && dir /s && pause"
   )
```

It opens different command prompts ...

Comment: it just opened the command prompts but its not running the commands

Comment: it should be `start cmd /c "cd \ & dir /s & pause"` so that newbies aren't confused.

Comment: start /min cmd /c batch1.bat && start program1.exe
start /min cmd /c batch2.bat && start program2.exe

https://superuser.com/questions/505077/batch-file-to-open-multiple-cmd-prompts#